# Best practice to normal re-render a value of a state/prop that is inside a useEffect without adding it as a dependency?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm trying to find a best practice to render a list of components inside the dom without adding many dependencies in the useEffect that would cause a completely re-render of the whole list every time.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const indices = props.indices;
    if(Object.keys(indices).length !== 0){
        const indicesToRender = Object.keys(indices).map((key: Extract<keyof IIndices, string>, index) => (
            <div key={key} className="p-field-radiobutton radio-indice">
                <RadioButton inputId={key} name="indice" value={indices[key]} onChange={(e) => props.onCheck(e.value)} checked={props.source === indices[key]} />
            </div>
        ))
        setIndicesDom(indicesToRender);
    }
}, [props.indices, props.source]);

return(
    <div className="indices">
       {indicesDom}
    </div>
)
```

In this example I'm trying to render a list of RadioButtons, and to me, as a dependency of the useEffect, there should be only the props.indices that is the object I need to wait to be filled  from the parent to create my components. However, as a property of the component RadioButton, there is a 'checked' property where I use my props.source to determine if the button should be checked or not. That props.source gets changed from the parent every time I click on a RadioButton so I would expect that it causes a normal re-render from react to change only the value of that props.source inside the component on the DOM so that the button gets visibly checked. However it doesn't cause the re-render and the only way I found is to add as a dependency of the useEffect also the props.source so that the useEffect re-run everytime the props.source gets changed. This also causes a re-render of the whole list and that would be a waste of performance because I only need to re-render the value of that property props.source and that would happen correctly if I would write the component inside the return() this way

```
return(
    <div className="indices">
      <RadioButton name="indice" value={"indice1"} onChange={(e) => props.onCheck(e.value)} checked={props.source === "indice1"} />
    </div>
)
```

Comment: Why not simply map the RadioButton to the props directly in the `return` rather than putting in the RadioButtons in the state?

Comment: I just do it as a practice to have a cleaner code inside the `return`. However even if I move the map method inside the `return` still, on every change of the props.source value, map() would be re-executed so the whole list re-rendered every time